# Query help, not getting right rows

Tags: sql-server

enter image description here> Write a select statement that returns InvoiceNumber, VendorName and InvoiceDate
from the Vendors and Invoices table. Use the following correlations for each table:

> 1. Vendors v
> 2. Invoices i
>
> Filter the results to return only rows where a balance is due

I should be getting back 11 rows but I am getting 114 rows.

```
Select InvoiceNumber, VendorName, InvoiceDate
From Vendors as v
join Invoices as i on v.VendorId = i.VendorID
where InvoiceTotal > 0
```

Comment: Can't really help you without seeing the data in question (a sample not all of it).

Comment: And by normal definition a balance means invoice total less any payments. All invoices should have a total (in general).

Comment: @Shawn you really need to add more information to your question or it will probably be closed. Most importantly add some sample data so we can see how the rows are related and why your query is not working. Just looking at the SQL there does not appear to be anything wrong, data will help people to help you. If the data is too large, put it on a file share as CSV so it can be downloaded.

Answer (score -1):

Query above looks good.

If you got unexpected number of rows in result it means (like @Dale-K mentioned in comment) wrong condition. `InvoiceTotal` does not look like *amount left to pay*.

Look for column like *InvoiceDue* or *InvoiceBalance*.

Or there is also column with *due date* and this should be added to condition (to find overdued invoices).

Or there is another table keeping payments which should be joined too.

Without structure of tables and sample data we can only guess.

However this looks like homework, so look for the column with current balance of invoice and use it.

Comment: Their is a column for InvoiceDue Date but I do get the same amount of rows

Comment: @Shawn only you know what defines an invoice as "having a balance" but I doubt its having a total as all invoices should have a total (normally)